# How to change data type of column in Data frame to Date from Char

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm messing with some columns in R using RStudio and have tried to change the data type of one of the columns from Char to Date.

I have used a few options and the one that came the closest was

```
data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(data$Date))
```

Though even this doesn't seem to work as it changes the values of the column to some weird values

i.e. from

[image]

To something like

[image]

I can't quite figure out why the transformation isn't working.

Here is my code up until that point

```
# load the tidyverse library
library("tidyverse")
setwd("C:/Users/ibrahim.cetinkaya/OneDrive - NTT/Desktop/data")
##################### Part A #####################
# data files (you need to specify the paths of the CSV files (e.g. relativeor absolute) )
files <- c("data/201808.csv",
       "data/201809.csv",
       "data/201810.csv",
       "data/201811.csv",
       "data/201812.csv",
       "data/201901.csv",
       "data/201902.csv",
       "data/201903.csv",
       "data/201904.csv",
       "data/201905.csv",
       "data/201906.csv",
       "data/201908.csv"
)

#Concatenate into one data frame. 
data <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  temp <- read_csv(files[i], skip = 7)
  data <- rbind(data, temp)
}
#View to verify
view(data)

#Part 2
#Remove vairables which have no data at all (All the data are na's)
#Remove variables that doesn't have adequate data (70% of the number of records are NA's)
data <- data[rowMeans(is.na(data))<=0.9,]
view(data)


#Change the column names to have no spaces between the words

names(data) <- gsub(" ", "_", names(data))
view(data)


#Convert Date to date type

#df2 <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(data), as.Date, format="%m-%d-%Y")

#data %>% mutate(data$Date==as.Date(Date, format = "%m.%d.%Y"))
data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(data$Date))
#^^^ This doesn't seem to be working properly ^^^


#Checking if it worked
typeof(data$Date)
view(data)
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
I want to be able to change the data type and then extract the month and use it for grouping some of the other data in my frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

and then to extract month

```
data$Month <- format(data$Date, "%m")
```

---

We can also use `lubridate`

```
data$date <- lubridate::mdy(data$date)
```

and use `month` to extract the month.

```
data$month <- month(data$date)
```

---

and with `anytime`

```
data$Date <- anytime::anydate(data$Date)
```

Comment: Thank you, ill try that now and see. Can you tell me what was wrong with mine?

Comment: @Ibbylun ohh..I didn't see your attempt. But I guess you are using dataframe name instead of column name. Should be `data %>% mutate_at(vars(date), as.Date, format="%m-%d-%Y")`